# install Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu

I have a Dell Inspiron P25T with Xubuntu 19.10.
I am trying to install Xubuntu 20.04 but the display looks like an 80 character wide display trying to show 82 characters.
Rectangular windows are stair-stepped trapezoids.
I have to press and hold the power key to shut down.
I tried to install Kubuntu and that worked but I would prefer Xubuntu.
Is there some video setting I could change to correct the problem?
I have searched for this issue but no matches, yet.

Comment: 1. I suggest that you wait for a month or two and try again using the 'daily' iso file (where there may be updated graphics drivers); 2. Since Kubuntu works, you could also try Lubuntu 20.04 LTS because it has the LXQt desktop environment, that has a lot in common with KDE of Kubuntu, and Lubuntu has a light footprint like Xubuntu; 3. You may also install Xubuntu 18.04.x LTS, which will be supported for another year, until April 2021, and by that time we can expect Xubuntu 20.04.x to be debugged and polished, so that it works also with the hardware in your computer.

Comment: @sudodus Thank you. I will look into Lubuntu and see if the problem with Xubuntu is resolved in the next few months.